# Color code of lines based on an array using Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am drawing multiple horizontal and vertical lines using `ax.hlines()` and `ax.vlines()` respectively. I want to assign values to these lines using the array `P` and the order of assignment is presented in the expected output.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
n=3
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i,200+200*j),10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        ax.hlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200, 200*n, zorder=0)
        ax.vlines(200+200*j+5*n, 200, 200*n, zorder=0)

ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.show()

#########################################
P=np.array([[1.9],
       [4.9],
       [6.1],
       [8.2],
       [1.8],
       [5.8],
       [9.7],
       [7.3],
       [8.9],
       [2.5],
       [9.9],
       [0.7]])

#########################################
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the values in array P?

Comment: The array ```P``` is mentioned at the bottom of the code.

Comment: I mean the colormap.

Comment: The colormap in the expected output is for illustration only. Based on the array ```P```, it will be in the range ```0-10``` since the min is 0.7 and max is 9.9

Comment: You are expecting a square because in your code every edge should be 200. But in your example.jpg, they seems to be not a square. As@Davide_sd said, it's because of overlapping. My code follows your order as you labeled from P[0]-P[11], and solves the overlapping.

Comment: There is a problem with the output. There are two missing 2 black squares at the top. Other than that, there should be 12 lines (horizontal and vertical) for 12 values according to array ```P```.

Comment: Sorry for that, because I only focued on the lines. But aren't there 12 lines?

Comment: Yes there are 12 lines. I checked the output. But it would be great to have 9 squares as I show in the expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246448/discussion-between-jkgalbraith-and-x-pie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values bar is added following @Davide_sd.

I'm not sure if this sovles your problem.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm


fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
n=3

P=np.array([[1.9],
       [4.9],
       [6.1],
       [8.2],
       [1.8],
       [5.8],
       [9.7],
       [7.3],
       [8.9],
       [2.5],
       [9.9],
       [0.7]])

color = cm.get_cmap('Blues')
norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10)
color_list = []
for i in range(len(P)):
    color_list.append(color(P[i]/10))
print(color_list)
id = 0
for j in range(0, n):
    for k in range(n-1):
        ax.hlines(200+200*(n-j-1)+5*n, 200*(k+1)+5*n, 200*(k+2)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
        id += 1

    for i in range(0, n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i, 200+200*j), 10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        if j < n-1:
            ax.vlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200*(n-1-j)+5*n, 200*(n-j)+5*n, zorder=0, colors=color_list[id])
            id += 1

cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=color, norm=norm))
cb.set_label("Values")
ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.show()
```

And the ouput is like:[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The number of squares is fine now but as I increase ```n``` say from 3 to 4, I see 3 vertical lines not appearing at the bottom. I am looking for a generic code which works for many ```n```. For ```n=4```, the shape of ```P``` should be ```(24,1)``` which means 24 different values for 24 different lines (horizontal and vertical combined).

Comment: Got it, I will update later.

Comment: Try to change "if j <2" to "if j < n-1"，I suppose it will work.

Comment: There's problem with ```n=4```. It makes multiple lines at a time at some places. Instead I want it to take 1 line at a time and pick values according to ```P```.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little confused. I have post the result when ```n=4```, and what do you mean by "it makes multiple lines at a time"

Comment: For ```n=4```, for every branch, there are 3 horizontal lines. It takes 1 value for the first two horizontal lines from left even when the array ```P``` consists of 24 distinct values. There is no problem with assigning values to the vertical lines.

Comment: Ofcourse you are right. I will update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a colormap, `Normalize` and `ScalarMappable` in order to create a colorbar.

Here is the procedure:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np

#########################################
P=np.array([[1.9],
       [4.9],
       [6.1],
       [8.2],
       [1.8],
       [5.8],
       [9.7],
       [7.3],
       [8.9],
       [2.5],
       [9.9],
       [0.7]])

#########################################

# normalize the values. Values between 0 and 10 will be
# normalized to values from 0 and 1.
norm = Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=10)
Pnorm = norm(P)
# choose an appropriate colormap
cmap = cm.Blues

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
n=3
k = 0
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        rect = mpl.patches.Rectangle((200+200*i,200+200*j),10*n, 10*n, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='black')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        # extract the color from the colormap
        ax.hlines(200+200*i+5*n, 200, 200*n, zorder=0, color=cmap(Pnorm[k]))
        ax.vlines(200+200*j+5*n, 200, 200*n, zorder=0, color=cmap(Pnorm[k]))
        k += 1

cb = fig.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm))
cb.set_label("Values")
ax.set_xlim(left = 0, right = 220*n)
ax.set_ylim(bottom = 0, top = 220*n)
plt.show()
```

There is a problem with the way you are currently plotting lines, as they are overlapping. You need to fix it!